# Enable cache on AWS RDS for MySQL

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, aws

I just upgraded my server to AWS, and I am using RDS for database. But here, it looks like the same query is taking such a long time as compared to my old server.

I was researching and found that there is RDS cache issue. It every time calls opening table and follow all the steps and in my server it was using cache so it was not opening tables every time. I am using MySQL on RDS.

I have hundreds of thousands of records in one one table. Can someone please help me to get good performance on RDS?

Answer (score 1):

You can tune performance using Parameter Groups. Some (unfortunately, not all) variables can be configured there.

Also, if you used AWS Database Migration make sure you have all the keys you need because they're not transferred by default.